# CSS background image resize dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, hover, background-image

Similar issue I've been dealing with for sometime now.  I've got a link that has a background image assigned to it via css.  I also have a hover image to work with it.  I dynamically resize the page image size, so that it can resize an image map.  I'm trying to add a Div so that there will be a printer icon you can mouseover and have it's hover icon appear.  When I leave everything fullsize, it will work, but once I resize the background and imagemap popups, the printer div resizes fine, but the background image in the div won't resize.

http://jsfiddle.net/trout0525/qfd58krc/1/

```
function mainLoad() {

    var imageElement = document.getElementById('jDirBackground');
    imgScale = currentScale(imageElement);
    alert("mainLoad imgScale: " + imgScale);
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('jDirMap');
    var imageMap = new imageMapResize(mapElement, imgScale);
    imageMap.resize();
    var printerIcon = new printerIconResize(imgScale);
    printerIcon.resize();

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally found a solution that I think is reasonable.  The main thing is that CSS3 is not powerful enough to do what I was hoping for, so I went back a bit on the HTML evolution chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/trout0525/qfd58krc/2/

I had hoped that CSS could handle the graphic resize, but it doesn't seem to be able to do it.  I did an old school bit of throwing a onmouseover and onmouseout:

```
onmouseover="imgHover(this)" onmouseout="imgLeave(this)"
```

and the code to meet it:

```
function imgHover (x) {
    x.src = "http://static.wixstatic.com/media/7a35ec_64af7af5864a4f2dad19c8c20855e532.jpg";
}
function imgLeave (x) {
    x.src = "http://www.mailersstore.com/images/SECAP-SA3150.jpg";
}
```

then I had to handle the resize in JavaScript of this:

```
function printerIconResize(imgScale) {
    var position = $('#printerDiv').position();
    var divWidth = $('#printerDiv').width();
    var divHeight = $('#printerDiv').height();

    var iconWidth = $('#printerIcon_link').width();
    var iconHeight = $('#printerIcon_link').height();

    // Get on screen image
    var screenImage = $("#printerIcon_link");

    // Create new offscreen image to test
    var theImage = new Image();
    theImage.src = screenImage.attr("src");

    // Get accurate measurements from that.
    iconWidth = theImage.width;
    iconHeight = theImage.height;

    this.resize = function() {
        var newTop = position.top * imgScale;
        var newLeft = position.left * imgScale;
        var newDivWidth = parseInt((divWidth * imgScale), 10);
        var newDivHeight = parseInt((divHeight * imgScale), 10);
        var newIconWidth = parseInt((iconWidth * imgScale), 10);
        var newIconHeight = parseInt((iconHeight * imgScale), 10);

        $('#printerDiv').offset({ top: newTop, left: newLeft });
        $('#printerDiv').width( newDivWidth );
        $('#printerDiv').height( newDivHeight );
        $('#printerIcon_link').width( newIconWidth );
        $('#printerIcon_link').height( newIconHeight );

        newPosition = $('#printerDiv').position();
        newDivWidth = $('#printerDiv').width();
        newDivHeight = $('#printerDiv').height();
        newIconWidth = $('#printerIcon_link').width();
        newIconHeight = $('#printerIcon_link').height();
        return true;
    };

    window.onresize = this.resize;
}
```

It does take it a while for the page to load and reload, but this is the best I could come up with now.  If you know a better way....

By the way, the JSFiddle code does not appear to work, but if you took off the site and tried it, it should be fine, except that the imgHover and imgLeave actually in a script area in the html file, not the js file.

Whew!!!  Time for a beer. (or three)